# Sequencial Workflow Using Visual Studio

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, reminder

I have created the sequential workflow in visual studio. I want to send email reminder before the due date on different interval and also if due date pass and user have not approved item then email should be sent.

How to send an email reminder in the sequential workflow?

Comment: For similar kind of activity, I have used console application. It runs daily and sends reminder mail accordingly. It gives better control to us than sequential workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing same for SharePoint App Development you can refer link below: 
 [Sending email messages from a workflow in an app for SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/09/18/step-by-step-sending-email-messages-from-a-workflow-in-an-app-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Also you can refer link from stackexchange where same question is answered for 2010 version.

[How to send an email in a visual studio sequential workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46159/how-to-send-an-email-in-a-visual-studio-sequential-workflow)

you can refer this link for 2013 version: [Send Email through Visual Studio Workflow in SharePoint 2013](http://sharepointvenividivici.typepad.com/sharepoint-customization/2015/08/send-email-through-visual-studio-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

Comment: Yes I know we can send email. But I have to send email reminder automatically before due date. How workflow will automatically trigger and send email.